How to protect key exchanging from the MITM attack
I'm trying to create a p2p protocol implementation using java. I wrote Diffie-Hellman algorithm, but then I faced with MITM attack. So, the question is: How to protect the key exchanging?

How I generate the keys:

public void generateKeys(){
        try {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);

            final KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();

            privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
            publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



Send them:

 private void sendPublickKey(){
        Message message = new Message(null, null, Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
        String json = JsonUtils.serializeData(new Data(Data.DataType.PUBLIC_KEY, message, null));
        out.println(json);
    }



Receive:

public void receivePublicKey(String encodedPublicKey){
        try {
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedPublicKey);
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey);
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DH");
            receivedPublicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

            generateSharedSecret();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


Generate a secret key:

private void generateSharedSecret() {
        try {
            KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
            keyAgreement.init(privateKey);
            keyAgreement.doPhase(receivedPublicKey, true);

            byte[] sharedSecret = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(sharedSecret, 0, 32, "AES");
            System.out.println("Current session key: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded()));

            _HCP = new HaritaCP();

            validateSecretKey();

            Logger.logMessage("Shared secret key generated successfully.", Logger.LogType.info);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Diffie-Hellman (DH) is designed to be used on an insecure channel, where MITM attacks are possible. An attacker will not be able to reconstruct the shared secret even if they have full access to the message exchanged between legitimate participants. The math is explained in the Wikipedia article.

@ixe013, I know how the algorithm works. But imagine that you are the "man in the middle". I send the public key to user2, and you intercept this key, so the user 2 will not receive it. You create a secret key with me, then you create a secret key with user2. In this case you will be able to read all data by intercepting it, decrypt it with your's-mine key, encrypt it with your's-user2's key and send it to him

@ixe013: The MITM has even better access than full access to the message exchanged between legitimate participants, so MiTM is possible.

Designing a crypto protocol is not what Stack Overflow is about, so this really isn't a programming question. If you want an example of a protocol that uses DH and protects against MiTM, take a look at the TLS protocol, particularly TLS 1.3.

Diffie-Hellman is a non-authenticated key-agreement protocol. A key can be exchange over an insecure channel, and it will be impossible for an attacker to know the key. But once a key is securely negotiated with someone, you have to authenticate the party you are talking to.
Asking for their credentials (password, API key, etc.) is conceptually sufficient, but insecure. The client would have no way to tell that the server is not storing their credentials and impersonating them in the future. A challenge based on the credentials (like in Kerberos) faces a similar problem, with the server knowing the credentials (or a derivative of it) for every client.
You'll need to add some kind of registration to your protocol to establish identity (over your secure connection). It would go something like this:

Diffie-Hellman key exchange
Client says "Hi, I am faniffs", here is my public key
Server looks up faniffs but does not have that record
Server creates a client entry for faniffs
Server says "Hello, I am server"
Server sends a random nonce encrypted using faniffs public key
Client answers back with the decrypted nonce, proving ownership of the private key

This is a crude replica of mutual TLS authentication. You could also look into other forms of authentication like OpenID Connect, if it makes sense in your application.

This is not at all how TLS client aka mutual auth works (or SSH2 client/user auth either), and only about one-third correct for SSLv2 which nobody has used for decades because it is broken and should not be used as an example for anything. And on top of that it doesn't actually authenticate or bind at all.

Right, thanks for pointing it out. For one, this is p2p and any attacker can perform those steps an infinity of times. Maybe "crude" was not a strong enough disclaimer... What I wanted to do is give a sense of the difference between key exchange and authentication. I'll gladly delete this answer if you think it harms more than it helps.

So is there a way to create protected from intercepting channel or something else? Or I should create a little server with just user's password and login?

Not that I know of. Creating another server (aka trusted third party) moves the problem over there. You must work with the assumption that the traffic can be intercepted and rerouted, and use different algorithms for different purposes (share a key, pick an encryption primitive, authenticate, etc.), so that an attacker will not be able to do anything (other than maybe block the connection). Each "layer" has its own attack. For example, an attacker could force users to fallback on a weak encryption scheme.

Now I'm thinking that I took a very complex project to do  Could you provide the libs or protocols, which can help me, please? (Other than TSL)

We were already far from SO question guidelines, not getting any closer... Maybe the XMPP protocol will meet your requirements - but it still might require a TLS connection (but with its own authentication protocol on top).

Okay, thanks, sir!
